# How to localize alert message box in Swift

Tags: swift, localization, xcode7, localizable.strings

My alert box message code is

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello!", message:
                            "Good Morning Everyone!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
```

I want to translate the text 
 **Hello** and **Good Morning Everyone!**.

How to implement this in swift?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSLocalizedString` for this.

```
let title = NSLocalizedString("Hello!", comment: "alertController title")
let message = NSLocalizedString("Good Morning Everyone!", comment: "alertController message")

let alertController = UIAlertController(
  title: title, 
  message: message, 
  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
```

Then `cd` into the project directory and use `genstrings` utility to generate the `Localizable.strings` file.
Then add it to the project, and select it.
In the File Inspector click on `Localize...`, then select the languages you want to use.
This will create the `Localizable.strings` files for the specific languages.

Or you can select your project then go to `Editor->Export For Localization...`
This will create an XLIFF file, in which you can do the translation,
then import it back using `Editor->Import Localizations...`

Answer (score 0):

**Now, I got the solution!**

```
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello!", message:
                            "Good Morning Everyone!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))


                        alertController.title = NSLocalizedString("Hello!", comment: "")
                        alertController.message = NSLocalizedString("Good Morning Everyone!", comment: "")
```